# pandas Series replace with backfill alternative

Tags: python, pandas

The documentation of [pandas.Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) includes an example:

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>> s.replace([1, 2], method='bfill')
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64
```

but it results now in a warning:

> FutureWarning: The 'method' keyword in Series.replace is deprecated
> and will be removed in a future version.

what would be then the alternate way of getting the same result stated in the example?

Answer (score 1):

The alternate code to get the same result could be:

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> import numpy as np
>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>> s.mask(s.isin([1,2])).bfill().fillna(s).convert_dtypes()
0    3
1    3
2    3
3    4
4    5
dtype: int64
```

In other use case of `replace` whose parameter is an scalar instead of a list, for example:

```
>> s.replace(2, method='bfill')
```

the alternative would be:

```
>> s.mask(s==2).bfill().fillna(s).convert_dtypes()
```

Comment: `s.mask(s.isin([1,2])).bfill()` is enough ;)

Comment: @mozway it doesn't work if the last element is 2. The method replace with method='bfill' leaves the element intact, but both of our methods replace the last element by NaN

Comment: that's true (I hadn't checked, just simplified your answer, my point was that `np.nan` is not needed in `mask`/`where` since it's the default and that `where(~x)` is the same a `mask(x)`), then use: `s.mask(s.isin([1,2])).bfill().fillna(s).convert_dtypes()`

Comment: @mozway I have adapted my answer with your suggestions. I think now is your answer :-) You can write your answer and I will vote for yours and delete mine :-)

Comment: Don't worry keep it like that, this is well deserved. Thank you for taking time to provide a Q/A that will help future users of pandas. You already have my upvotes.